# add and remove multiple tag by onclick to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a textarea and list of tags from database( already queried and displayed under the textarea ) and want to add these tags (seperated by comma) on textarea and remove if the tag is already there as user click on them.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post your js code as well as your html

Comment: Please post some code. So that we can know what you tried....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you mean, please have a look at this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/QyqYW/1/

The code is below. `tags` would come from the server and `selectedTags` is the managed array of current selections. you could load data from the server into `selectedTags` too if necessary, if for instance editing an existing tagged post. If you did this, you'd refactor the code in the `click()` function out to its own function so it could be run on document ready too.

I've included some class toggling and a debug screen so you can see what is going on.

HTML

```
<textarea id="tags"></textarea>
<div id="tagButtons"></div>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

and JavaScript

```
var tags = [
  'JavaScript',    
  'jQuery',
  'HTML5',    
  'CSS3'
];

var selectedTags = [];

for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
  var el = $('<span>').text(tags[i]);
  $('#tagButtons').append(el);
}

$('#tagButtons span').click(function(){
  var val = $(this).text();
  var index = selectedTags.indexOf(val);
  if(index > -1) {
    var removed = selectedTags.splice(index,1); 
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $('#debug').prepend($('<div>').html('Removed: ' + removed));
  } else {
    selectedTags.push(val);
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#debug').prepend($('<div>').html('Added: ' + val));
  }
  $('#tags').val(selectedTags.join(', '));
});
```

**EDIT** Here is one that works in both directions http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/QyqYW/14/

Comment: Thank you very much @joevallender, when i try to load tags from database `$result = mysql_query("select tagname from tags");
$response = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
 $response[] = $row;

} $jsonData = json_encode($response); 
<script>
  var tags= <?= $jsonData ?>;</script>
`  got error SyntaxError: invalid XML markup
[Break On This Error]  

var tags= <?= $jsonData ?>;

Comment: Cheers mate. Is the code you've posted just to share with others or do you have a question about that too? I'd have thought you'd be wanting to write json_encode($response) instead of $jsonData - ah, just see you've edit your comment while I've been typing :-)

Comment: You've tagged the question as PHP... so wouldn't it be <?php print $jsonData ?>

Comment: thanks for the offer, but just put your questions up here on stackoverflow and I'm sure the community can solve them all! :)

Comment: thats so generous @joevallender.

Comment: when i add new tags by typing into textarea[#tags] after that clicking on any tag from var tags[],it removes the added tags on textarea, is it possible to add new tags along tags from database