# append new text on textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a tag system based on http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/QyqYW/1/ but when i try to add new tag by typing in textarea, it works fine but when i click on any tag, previous new  text will be removed.

## HTML

```
<textarea id="tags"></textarea>
<div id="tagButtons"></div>
```

## Javascript

```
var tags = [
  'JavaScript',    
  'jQuery',
  'HTML5',    
  'CSS3'
];

var selectedTags = [];

for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
  var el = $('<span>').text(tags[i]);
  $('#tagButtons').append(el);
}

$('#tagButtons span').click(function(){
  var val = $(this).text();
  var index = selectedTags.indexOf(val);
  if(index > -1) {
    var removed = selectedTags.splice(index,1); 
    $(this).removeClass('selected');

  } else {
    selectedTags.push(val);
    $(this).addClass('selected');

  }
  $('#tags').val(selectedTags.join(', '));
});
​
```

Comment: You mean you want to consider tags besides the ones that are in the `tags` array?

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, I highly recommend the [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#tags) plugin which has very nice tag support already, which allows selection from existing tags or adding new ones.

Comment: @João yes i want to add new tags on textarea besides the tags array(which is from database)

Comment: do you really need to toggle tag?

Comment: yes i want toggle tag to show its already selected

Comment: i think the idea of 'suggested' tags were required as well as entering anything. I agree that a plugin is a good way to go, I just fancied typing up some JS :) see my answer and link to original question below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line

```
$('#tags').val(selectedTags.join(', '));
```

It's overwriting what was in the `textarea` before.

**EDIT:**

Try it : 
http://jsfiddle.net/QyqYW/92/

```
var tags = [
  'JavaScript',    
  'jQuery',
  'HTML5',    
  'CSS3',
  'PHP'
],
keys = "";

var selectedTags = [];

for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
  var el = $('<span>').text(tags[i]);
  $('#tagButtons').append(el);
}

//changed click event to "on" event.. 
//it seems that click doesn't bind to dynamically added elements
$('#tagButtons').on("click" , "span" , function(){
     //Checks if you've forgot to type "," and then adds your tag
     if(keys != ""){
          selectedTags.push(keys);                                   
          $('#debug').prepend($('<div>').html('Added: ' + keys));
          var newEl = $('<span class="selected">').text(keys);
          $('#tagButtons').append(newEl);
          $('#tags').focus().val(selectedTags.join(', ') + ", ");                                    
          keys = "";
      }

      var val = $(this).text();
      var index = selectedTags.indexOf(val);
      if(index > -1) {
          var removed = selectedTags.splice(index,1); 
          $(this).removeClass('selected');
          $('#debug').prepend($('<div>').html('Removed: ' + removed));
          $('#tags').focus().val(selectedTags.join(', ') + ", ");
      } else {
          selectedTags.push(val);
          $(this).addClass('selected');
          $('#debug').prepend($('<div>').html('Added: ' + val));
          $('#tags').focus().val(selectedTags.join(', ') + ", ");                                    
      }                                                      


});

//adds tag after you type ",".. 
//if you forgot to, look above the first line in the on event
$("#tags").keydown(function(evt){                               
     if(evt.which == 188){
         selectedTags.push(keys);                                   
         $('#debug').prepend($('<div>').html('Added: ' + keys));
         var newEl = $('<span class="selected">').text(keys);
         $('#tagButtons').append(newEl);
         $('#tags').val(selectedTags.join(', '));                                       
         keys = "";
     } else if(evt.which ==8){ 
     //for after adding tag you can't use Backspace to delete it.
     //remove tag from butotns
         if(keys == ""){
         evt.preventDefault();
     } else {
         keys += String.fromCharCode(evt.which).toLowerCase();
     }

});
```

Comment: `$('#tags').val(selectedTags.join(', '));` is used for adding tags when user click on it

Comment: I know, when you write some tag in that `textarea` and click on any tags buttons, this line get executed, replacing all what were in that `textarea` with the result of `selectedTags.join(', ')`, which means deleting what you've typed.

Answer (score 1):

I continued working on the jsfiddle on your original question
[add and remove multiple tag by onclick to textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087694/add-and-remove-multiple-tag-by-onclick-to-textarea)

see http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/QyqYW/14/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).text();
```

Abowe, will only return value which was rendered oryginaly into DOM from html. Whatever you type into textarea is not there yet, you have to hook on `('#tags').on('keyup' function () {});`
and store what was typed in order to include it to textarea later.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I think you should just put the tags into a seperate div or input. They should be stored seperately in a db anyway.